# How can I handle conditions in Conda environment configuration files?

Tags: python, conda

I have a Conda environment configuration file that looks like this:

```
name: something
dependencies:
  - tensorflow-gpu
  - cudatoolkit
  - foo
  - bar
  - ...
  - baz
```

Now, in some systems (those not having a CUDA-enabled GPU), the environment would look like this instead:

```
name: something
dependencies:
  - tensorflow
  - foo
  - bar
  - ...
  - baz
```

I am not sure if I can handle this properly with Conda. With `pip` and `requirements-gpu.txt` I can easily include another `requirements-common.txt` file, but I have not found that option for Conda.

- Can I put an "if" somewhere to check for GPU+CUDA and decide which dependencies to install?
- Can I put an "if" somewhere that is dependent on an argument passed to the `conda env create` command? (i.e.: `--flag cpu` or `--flag gpu`)
- Can I extract the common dependencies and somehow include them from two different top-level environment configuration files? (i.e.: `environment-cpu.yaml`, `environment-gpu.yaml` and `environment-common.yaml`)
- Maybe something different?

Comment: Did you try the third approach and specify multiple `-f` to the `create` command?

Comment: @darthbith It seems that is not possible.

Comment: Then it seems like you'll have to do two steps, one with the common dependencies and one with the others. There is a `conda env update` command that updates an environment with specs from a file.